# Is it necessary to export base method extensions in an R package? Documentation implications?

Tags: r, documentation, namespaces, extension-methods, package

In principle, I could keep these extensions not-exported, and this would also allow me to not-add redundant documentation for these already well-documented methods, while still also passing `R CMD check myPackage` without any reported `WARNING`s.

What are some of the drawbacks, if any? Is this possibly recommended to keep extensions of basic methods compartmentalized within the package that defines them? Alternatively, will this make it more difficult for another package to depend on mine, if certain core method-extensions are not exported?

For example, if I don't document and don't export the following:

`setMethod("show", "myPackageSpecialClass", function(object){ show(NA) })`

I'm trying to flesh-out some of these finer details of best-practices with namespaces and base method extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't export the methods, then users (either at the command line or trying to use your classes and methods in their own package via imports) won't be able to use them -- your class will be displayed with the `show,ANY-method`.

You are not documenting the generic `show`, but rather the method appropriate for your class, `show,myPackageSpecialClass-method`. If in your NAMESPACE you

```
import(methods)
exportMethods(show)
```

(note that there is no way to export just some methods on the generic show) and provide no documentation, `R CMD check` will complain

```
* checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING
Undocumented S4 methods:
  generic 'show' and siglist 'myPackageSpecialClass'
All user-level objects in a package (including S4 classes and methods)
should have documentation entries.
See the chapter 'Writing R documentation files' in the 'Writing R
Extensions' manual.
```

Your example (I know it was not meant to be a serious show method :) ) is a good illustration for why methods might be documented -- explaining to the user why every time they try and display the object they get `NA`, when they were expecting some kind of description about the object.

One approach to documentation is to group methods with the class into a single Rd file, `myPackageSpecialClass-class.Rd`. This file would contain an alias

```
\alias{show,myPackageSpecialClass-method}
```

and a Usage

```
\S4method{show}{myPackageSpacialClass}(object)
```

This works so long as no fancy multiple dispatch is used, i.e., it is clear to which class a method applies. If the user asks for help with `?show`, they are always pointed toward the methods package help page. For help on your methods / class, they'd need to ask for that specific type of help. There are several ways of doing this but my favorite is

```
class ? myPackageSpecialClass
method ? "show,myPackageSpecialClass"
```

This will not be intuitive to the average user; the (class|method) ? ... formulation is not widely used, and the specification of "generic,signature" requires a lot of understanding about how S4 works, including probably a visit to `selectMethod(show, "myPackageSpecialClass")` (because the method might be implemented on a class that myPackageSpecialClass inherits from) or `showMethods(class="myPackageSpecialClass", where=getNamespace("myPackage"))` (because you're wondering what you can do with myPackageSpecialClass).

Comment: But you don't _have_ to document exported methods, right?  (That's certainly the case for S3)

Comment: exported methods need to be documented; I added this to the answer.

Comment: Martin, when you say "One approach to documentation is to group methods with the class," do you mean document most/all of the new method extensions for that class in one class-doc? E.g. myPackageSpecialClass-class.Rd would include documentation for the tweaks to base methods that are extended. And in that approach is there a way to avoid the disambiguation screen for `?show` (in our example)?

Comment: @PaulMcMurdie -- tried to update the response, yes one approach is to document new methods with the class that they operate on. But no, you don't document `show` again, so there is no disambiguation needed.

Comment: @hadley I have created a follow-up question about how to accomplish this with Roxygen2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947483/add-class-specific-alias-without-generic-alias-using-roxygen2 ; since the generic alias is added automatically to the `@rdname` target, which I think we don't want in this case.