# Documenting and Exporting an S4 generic method that already exists in base

Tags: r, package, r-s4, roxygen2

My problem is essentially the same as outlined in [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947483/how-to-add-class-specific-alias-without-generic-alias-using-roxygen2) that resulted in a filed, and successfully closed bug report.

Given an existing `S4 generic`, in my case `diag` and `diag<-`, I wish to export an implementation for an `S4 class` from another package.

Reading through [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935523/is-it-necessary-to-export-base-method-extensions-in-an-r-package-documentation) I have discovered that i can successfully export these functions if I use the tags `@exportMethod diag<-` and `@exportMethod diag` respectively, but I can't get the documentation to work.

The first thread and subsequent closed bug report, suggests that the following should work (in this case for the method `show`):

```
#' @export
#' @aliases show,myPkgSpClass-method
#' @rdname myPkgSpClass-class
setMethod("show", "myPkgSpClass", function(object){ show(NA) })
```

However when I try to do the following for `diag`, I get an error when i try to build:

```
#' @export
#' @aliases diag<-,big.matrix-method
#' @rdname bigmatrix-diag
setMethod("diag<-", signature("big.matrix"), function(x, value) {
  SetDiag(x@address, value) # C++ implementation
  x
})

#' @export
#' @aliases diag,big.matrix-method
#' @rdname bigmatrix-diag
setMethod("diag", signature("big.matrix"), function(x) {
  GetDiag(x@address) # C++ implementation
})
```

**The error:** `Error : Sections \title, and \name must exist and be unique in Rd files`.

**Clarification:** Currently no implementation of `diag` is available for this class.

**EDIT: Resolving the error:** 
I can resolve this error, but not without clobbering the existing documentation for `diag`.

If I add a unique name and title as follows it will successfully builds:

```
#' @name diag
#' @title Extract and Replace the diagonal from a big.matrix
#' @aliases diag<-,big.matrix-method
#' @docType methods
#' @exportMethod diag<-
#' @rdname bigmatrix-diag
setMethod("diag<-", signature("big.matrix"), function(x, value) {
  SetDiag(x@address, value)
  x
})

#' @name diag
#' @title Extract and Replace the diagonal from a big.matrix.
#' @aliases diag,big.matrix-method
#' @docType methods
#' @exportMethod diag
#' @rdname bigmatrix-diag
setMethod("diag", signature("big.matrix"), function(x) {
  GetDiag(x@address)
})
```

But when i type `?diag` in an R session I get the error:

`Error in (function (path, query, ...)  : replacement has length zero`

Which i think means it`s finding two helpfiles for`diag`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this ?

```
#' @name diag
#' @aliases diag,big.matrix-method
#' @export diag
#' @rdname bigmatrix-diag
setMethod("diag", signature("big.matrix"), function(x) {
  GetDiag(x@address) # C++ implementation
})
```

Comment: See update in original question. I can get past that error, but not without clobbering the existing documentation for `diag`.

Comment: Ok,  try the alias,  I mean the full name in the @name then.

Comment: It compiles, but I'm not able to access the documentation. I'm also really unsure what the end result should look like in my case in terms of successfully linking the documentation.

Comment: in the documentation, go to the list of packages, click on yours, you should see your method listed as "diag,big.matrix-method" or something like this

Comment: I don't see it listed under `?diag`, I can only locate the documentation if i type `??\`diag,big.matrix-method\``